TV show with court trial and AI Judges
I'm looking for the name of a TV show. It's sci-fi and came out sometime back (I don't remember the exact period). The plot is something like this:
There was some sort of a court trial and there were 3 AI (Artificial Intelligence) judges. In the end, the defendant manages to get them to blow up because of some contradictory arguments he posed for them.
I know this is pretty vague, but I was hoping someone might remember it.

Reminds me a bit of the General on the original Prisoner. Could it have been that old?

If you actually remember seeing it, were the AIs distinctly robotic or near-human looking? Retro bots, futuristic bots, or android-like with skin and everything?

Is it any surprise that searching for robot judges gets me Judge Dredd? :P

Also, just to be sure, was it live action, animated, puppets(:P)

@Walt that's a good recommendation...interesting plot...

This is an extreme longshot, especially as I think that visakh would have mentioned if the show was puppet based, but there was an episode of a 60s British childrens' Sci Fi series that used puppets a la Thunderbirds (in fact same people just earlier) that featured the character being put on trial on a planet of robots- complete with robo jury and judge and exploding. 
Fireball XL5- Episode "Trial By Robot" (1963) summary:

Robots have vanished from four planets –and the disappearances are
  linked to visits by a famous robot scientist, Prof. Himber. When
  Robert also goes missing, Steve and Mat undertake the three-month
  journey to Planet 82, only to be put on trial by the mad professor
  –the ruler of his kidnapped robot race!

Youtube video of the full episode:




Thank you...:-) I don't really remember anything about the TV show, but as per the looks of it, this is the one...:-)
